# Relationship by custom property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

That is my database code:

```
public class User {
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Vote> Votes {get; set;}

    public User() {
        Votes = new List<Vote>();
    }
}

public class Video {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int OnsiteId {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Vote> Votes {get; set;}

    public Video() {
        Votes = new List<Vote>();
    }
}

public class Vote {
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int VideoOnsiteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VideoOnsiteId")]
    public Video Video { get; set; }    
}
```

For some reason `Votes` table contains `VideoOnsiteId` column which refers to `Video.Id` instead `Video.OnsiteId`. The result of this is I cant add a row to the database, becase I am getting conflitct with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. How can I change that?

Comment: What did you expect? A foreign key always references an entity primary key, which is by default the `Id` property. I don't get what your problem is, could you post the code where you try to create the objects?

Comment: I just explained that in my question. I dont want to refer to the `Id`. I want to refer ot the `OnsiteId`.

Comment: Then remove the `Id` property on `Video` and declare `OnsiteId` as the primary key. But still, I don't get what you're trying to do, but I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong elsewhere. Please show your code.

Comment: I can't remove it. I want to have `Id` and `OnSiteId`, but I want to my foreignKey as `OnSiteId`, NOT `Id`.

Comment: You can't. EF is based on RDBMS concepts. EF6 only allows you to create FK which is referencing the PK of the principal. EF Core also allows you to reference alternate unique key. You seem to want to create "logical" relationship, which is not possible.

Comment: Have you tried to set [Key] over OnsiteId property?